# how to add 2 list items to hashmap in java

Tags: java, collections

Hi I have 2 arraylist one list of userNames and another List of city. I want to add it to HashMap so that I can match user to city exactly.

```
List user : a1,b1,c1
List City : abc,null,def
```

I want to add it to `HashMap map = new HashMap();`
then if I read a1 key it should give value abc

```
a1=abc
b1=null
c1=def
.....
```

Comment: Okay, so what have you tried so far, and what happened? Ideally, show what you've tried in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: `IntStream.range(0, users.size()).boxed().collect(Collectors.toMap(users::get, cities::get))`

Comment: when I put map.put (list1,list2) its taking as a1,null b1,null c1, null and null,abc null,null null,def its not adding a1 to abc and then b1 to null and then c1 to def like on.

Answer (score 2):

```
 Map<String, String> map= new HashMap<String, String>();
 Iterator<String> i1 = user.iterator();
 Iterator<String> i2 = city.iterator();
 while (i1.hasNext() && i2.hasNext()) {
    map.put(i1.next(), i2.next());
  }
```

**For Java 8**

```
IntStream.range(0, users.size())
     .boxed()
     .collect(toMap(users::get, cities::get)));
```

Comment: when I put map.put (list1,list2) its taking as     a1,null   b1,null c1, null   and null,abc null,null null,def    its not adding a1 to abc and then b1 to null and then c1 to def like on...

Comment: Pls can you add code here?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```
Map<String, String> hash= new HashMap<String, String>();
for (int i=0;i<user.size();i++){
        hash.put(user.get(i),city.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add it in for loop example

```
for(int i = 0; i< user.size(); i++){
    map.put(user.get(i), city.get(i));
}
```